# Unity placing an if statement out of a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a Unity 3D game and I want to check in a script if the user is in the third level. If true, then  `timeLeft = 120;` otherwise  `timeLeft = 90;`. I tried implementing this simple if statement into the a script but I get:

`Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

If I put the statement into the start method I get:

```
The name 'timeLeft' does not exist in the current context
```

How to fix it?

**Timer.cs**

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collide _collide;
    Text instruction;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        instruction = GetComponent<Text>();
        InvokeRepeating("time", 0, 1);
    }

    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == 7)
         int timeLeft = 120;
    else int timeLeft = 90;
    
    private void time()
    {
        int buildIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        
        if (_collide.obji <= 0 && timeLeft > 0)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(buildIndex switch { 1 => 2, 3 => 5, 7 => 9 });
        else if (_collide.obji > 0 && timeLeft <= 0)
            SceneManager.LoadScene(buildIndex switch { 1 => 3, 3 => 6, 7 => 8 });
       
        if (timeLeft > 0)
        {
            timeLeft -= 1;
            instruction.text = (timeLeft).ToString();
        }
        else if (timeLeft <= 0)
            instruction.text = "0";
    }
}
```

[image: View]

Comment: Why `if` statement cannot be in `Start` method? Also `timeLeft` should be defined as a class field...

Comment: Because of **The name 'timeLeft' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: You have a misunderstanding how class declaration works. Except for members and other declarations (nested class, delegates,...) all the code has to be within a method.

Comment: This doesn't make sense on a fundamental level. When would the if statement get called? If you want it to be called when ever that statement is true, then that belongs in the update function which checks every frame.

Answer (score 2):

Since timeLeft is used over the class, it cannot be declared in a method. 
Move it up and place your code in the start.

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    int timeLeft;
    void Start()
    {
        instruction = GetComponent<Text>();
        InvokeRepeating("time", 0, 1);

        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == 7)
        {
            timeLeft = 120;
        }
        else
        {
            timeLeft = 90;
        }
/*
        timeLeft = (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == 7) ? 120 : 90;
*/
    }
}
```

Commented line is same, just written different.

Comment: I get Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Comment: Check that you have all the matching curly braces. It says you are missing one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `_timeLeft` field and then to put your `if` statement within a method. For example:

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collide _collide;
    Text instruction;

    int _timeLeft;

    void Start()
    {
        instruction = GetComponent<Text>();
        InitializeTimeLeft();
        InvokeRepeating("time", 0, 1);
    }

    void InitializeTimeLeft()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == 7)
        {
            _timeLeft = 120;
        }
        else
        {
            _timeLeft = 90;
        }
    }

    void time()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```